# How to output query result one by one bu using JavaScript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have query which pulls out some records. I display the result in rows. I have a button 'process' next to each row and when user click the button it does a change in database.

My problem is that i would like to change the way records are displayed. Instead of just displaying in rows; I want them to be displayed one by one.

So For Example, First record shows with 'Process' button, when I click button, it does the change in database and shows next record. So result would appear one by one.

I could not find any good examples after my research. Is there any example available or maybe any plugins.

What is the best approach to take on this.

Thanks in advance.

**Code**

**Query PHP**

Query which pulls out some records.

```
           $select_stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli_web1, "SELECT safetyinspectionperiodic_sip.id_sip, agsigns_db2.developers_dvp.id_dvp, agsigns_db2.developers_dvp.name_dvp, agsigns_db2.developers_dvp.region_dvp, agsigns_db2.developers_dvp.maintenancelocation_dvp,agsigns_db2.safetyinspectionperiodic_sip.idrou_sip
              FROM  safetyinspectionperiodic_sip 
              Inner JOIN developers_dvp
              ON safetyinspectionperiodic_sip.iddvp_sip = developers_dvp.id_dvp 
              Where agsigns_db2.safetyinspectionperiodic_sip.idrou_sip = ?");

              $select_stmt->bind_param("i", $route_id);
              $select_stmt->bind_result($id_sip,$id_dvp, $name_dvp, $region_dvp, $maintenancelocation_dvp, $idrou_sip);
              $select_stmt->execute();
              $select_stmt->store_result();

               if($select_stmt->num_rows > 0){

              while ($select_stmt->fetch()) {
                  $array2[] = array(
                      "id_sip"=>$id_sip,
                      "id_dvp" => $id_dvp,
                      "name_dvp" => $name_dvp,
                      "region_dvp" => $region_dvp,
                      "maintenancelocation_dvp" => $maintenancelocation_dvp,
                      "idroute" => $idrou_sip

                  );
              }
}
```

**This is how I currently display records.**

```
        if (!empty($array2)){
          foreach ($array2 as $key => $value) { ?>
              <div class="panel panel-default center-block developerinfo">
                  <div class="panel-body">
                      <div class=row>
                          <div class="col-md-12">
                              <h2 style="color:orangered" class="text-center">SIP</h2>
                              <img alt="" class="center-block"style="width:20%;"src="../../css/collecting/logo.png">
                              <h2 class="text-center"><?php echo $value['name_dvp']; ?></h2>
                              <h3 class="text-center">(<?php echo $value['region_dvp']; ?>)</h3>
                              <h3 class="text-center">D<?php echo $value['id_dvp']; ?></h3>
                              <h2 style="color:orangered" class="text-center"><?php echo $value['maintenancelocation_dvp']; ?></h2>

                              <img alt="" class=" center-block developerlocationselection check cursor selection-button" src="../../css/collecting/route-select.png" name="<?php echo $value['name_dvp']; ?>" region = "(<?php echo $value['region_dvp']; ?>)" id="D<?php echo $value['id_dvp']; ?>" location="<?php echo $value['maintenancelocation_dvp']; ?>" routeid="<?php echo $value['idroute']; ?>"sipid="<?php echo $value['id_sip']; ?>">

                              <ul id="developercheckbox">
                              <input type="checkbox" class="developernames" name="developernames"  style="display:none;">
                              </ul>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <?php
              }
          }
```

It will display result rows after one another.

I want result rows to be displayed one by one.

**Images**

This is current visual of result. 
[current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnlGN.png)

The result appear like this on top of each other and user have to scroll a lot.

I want result to appear as it is but one by one so user have no scrolling to do.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't provide a code sample and sample outputs. Refer to [`How do I ask a good question?`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello @Alexx. I have edited my original question.

Comment: Can you get a screenshot of what your output looks like and a small edit of what you want to see?

Comment: Hello @Alex. I have edited the question

Comment: Instead of scrolling, you want to paginate it?

Comment: Pretty much yes

Comment: One last question, Do you want to [`lazy load`](https://blog.stackpath.com/glossary/lazy-loading/), or want to have everything loaded and then `CSS` just does the pagination?

Comment: Rather have everything loaded and than the pagination is better idea to me.